# Concatenate files with same partial id BASH

Tags: bash

I have a directory with many fq.gz files. I want to loop over the filenames and concatenate any files with the same partial ID. For example out of the 1000 files in the directory, these six need to be concatenated into a single file (as they share the same ID From "L1" onwards)

> 141016-FC012-L1-N707-S504--123V_pre--Hs--R1.fq.gz
>   141031-FC01229-L1-N707-S504--123V_pre--Hs--R1.fq.gz
>   141020-FC01209-L1-N707-S504--123V_pre--Hs--R1.fq.gz
>   141027-FC013-L1-N707-S504--123V_pre--Hs--R1.fq.gz
>   141023-FC01219-L1-N707-S504--123V_pre--Hs--R1.fq.gz

Can anyone help??

Comment: going to need to be more specific about partial ID and what entails that

Comment: So the filename from 'L1' to the end of the filename will match as shown in the example

Comment: In what order do you want to concatenate them?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best way, but this might do what you need:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' id; do
    cat *"$id" > "/some/location/${id%.fq.gz}_grouped.fq.gz"
done < <(printf '%s\0' *.fq.gz | cut -zd- -f3- | sort -uz)
```

This will create files with the following format:

```
<ID>_grouped.fq.gz
L1-N707-S504--123V_pre--Hs--R1_grouped.fq.gz
...
...
```

Comment: Maybe explain that `cut -d- -f3-` is the magic sauce which extracts stuff from after the second dash in the filename. IIRC the `-z` option is a GNU extension. The OP is still not very clear on whether this is actually what they mean by "partial filename".